# How to convert Unix time / time since the epoch to standard date and time?

Tags: time, rust, rust-chrono

I'm using the chrono crate; after some digging I discovered the `DateTime` type has a function `timestamp()` which could generate epoch time of type `i64`. However, I couldn't find out how to convert it back to `DateTime`.

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::*;

fn main() {
    let date = chrono::UTC.ymd(2020, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
    println!("{}", start_date.timestamp());
    // ...how to convert it back?
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You first need to create a `NaiveDateTime` and then use it to create a `DateTime` again:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let datetime = Utc.ymd(2020, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
    let timestamp = datetime.timestamp();
    let naive_datetime = NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(timestamp, 0);
    let datetime_again: DateTime<Utc> = DateTime::from_utc(naive_datetime, Utc);

    println!("{}", datetime_again);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d8a143e54bce5fd039fa52773a1855c6&version=stable)

Comment: I managed to find a similar usage in [thisplace](https://docs.rs/chrono/*/src/chrono/datetime.rs.html#42), but apparently your answer is more concise and friendly. thank you!

Comment: 2021 answer at the bottom https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058251/3458484

Comment: Utc.ymd is deprecated: https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.ymd

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I'm missing something, or chrono expanded its feature set in the meantime, but its 2021 and at least since chrono 0.4.0 there appears to be a cleaner way to do it:

https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/#conversion-from-and-to-epoch-timestamps

```
use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, Utc};

// Construct a datetime from epoch:
let dt = Utc.timestamp(1_500_000_000, 0);
assert_eq!(dt.to_rfc2822(), "Fri, 14 Jul 2017 02:40:00 +0000");

// Get epoch value from a datetime:
let dt = DateTime::parse_from_rfc2822("Fri, 14 Jul 2017 02:40:00 +0000").unwrap();
assert_eq!(dt.timestamp(), 1_500_000_000);
```

So your full conversion should look like this:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::*;

fn main() {
    let start_date = chrono::Utc.ymd(2020, 1, 1).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
    let ts = start_date.timestamp();
    println!("{}", &ts);
    let end_date = Utc.timestamp(ts, 0);
    assert_eq!(end_date, start_date);
}
```

Comment: Utc.ymd is deprecated https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.ymd

Comment: True, but part of his questions code as well.
I'll look into it on monday, how I'd update my answer for this year :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`parse_duration`](https://github.com/zeta12ti/parse_duration/) crate: https://docs.rs/parse_duration/2.1.0/parse_duration/

```rust
extern crate parse_duration;
use parse_duration::parse;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    // 1587971749 seconds since UNIX_EPOCH
    assert_eq!(parse("1587971749"), Ok(Duration::new(1587971749, 0)));

    // One hour less than a day
    assert_eq!(parse("1 day -1 hour"), Ok(Duration::new(82_800, 0)));

    // Using exponents
    assert_eq!(
        parse("1.26e-1 days"),
        Ok(Duration::new(10_886, 400_000_000))
    );

    // Extra things will be ignored
    assert_eq!(
        parse("Duration: 1 hour, 15 minutes and 29 seconds"),
        Ok(Duration::new(4529, 0))
    );
}
```