# How do I convert a SystemTime to ISO 8601 in Rust?

Tags: rust, datetime-format, iso8601

I have a `SystemTime` variable and I want to get the ISO 8601 format from that date.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [chrono](https://docs.rs/chrono/newest/chrono/index.html) package is the right tool for the job here.  `SystemTime` may or may not be UTC, and chrono takes care of many irritating little details.

```
use chrono::prelude::{DateTime, Utc};

fn iso8601(st: &std::time::SystemTime) -> String {
    let dt: DateTime<Utc> = st.clone().into();
    format!("{}", dt.format("%+"))
    // formats like "2001-07-08T00:34:60.026490+09:30"
}
```

To customize the format differently, see the [`chrono::format::strftime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/newest/chrono/format/strftime/index.html) docs.

Comment: `std::time::SystemTime` is tagged with the `Clone` trait so passing a value instead of a reference should be preferred here.

Comment: Could you explain "SystemTime may or may not be UTC"? I don't see that mentioned in the docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714786/10238) to a similar question says "SystemTime itself is completely independent of timezones."

Answer (score 17):

Convert it to a [`chrono::DateTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.to_rfc3339) then use [`to_rfc3339`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.to_rfc3339):

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc}; // 0.4.15
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let now = SystemTime::now();
    let now: DateTime<Utc> = now.into();
    let now = now.to_rfc3339();

    println!("{}", now);
}
```

```
2020-10-01T01:47:12.746202562+00:00
```

The docs [explain the naming choice](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.parse_from_rfc3339) of the methods:

> ISO 8601 allows some freedom over the syntax and RFC 3339 exercises that freedom to rigidly define a fixed format

See also:

- [How to convert Unix time / time since the epoch to standard date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42572107/155423)

Comment: You can also use the following .format() string to represent something close to JavaScript's .toISOString() function: `Utc::now().format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%.3fZ")` to get something like this: `2022-12-29T00:00:00.000Z` 
Playground Link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7cc9bcdc4022347b8a38bd81c84df3e9

Comment: in the latest version of chrono 0.4.23, it says here https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.to_rfc3339 that its _"Available on 
crate features alloc or std
 only."_, which required me to add `features = ["alloc"]` to Cargo.toml like this: `chrono = { version = "0.4.23", default_features = false, features = ["alloc"] }`

Comment: but i got the time without SystemTime because i couldn't get it to work, i just used chrono with `let now: DateTime<Utc> = Utc::now();` and added features `features = ["alloc", "clock"]`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [time](https://crates.io/crates/time) crate ([doc](https://docs.rs/time)). With the latest alpha release  (0.3.0-ALPHA-0) you can use
`format_into()` method while providing a `&mut impl io::Write`. Alternatively, you can simply use the `format()` method which is also compatible with older stable releases.

```
use time::{
    format_description::well_known::Rfc3339, // For 0.3.0-alpha-0
    // Format::Rfc3339, // For 0.2 stable versions
    OffsetDateTime
};
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn to_rfc3339<T>(dt: T) -> String where T: Into<OffsetDateTime> {
    dt.into().format(&Rfc3339)
}

fn main() {
   let now = SystemTime::now();
   println!("{}", to_rfc3339(now));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20time%3A%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Format%3A%3ARfc3339%2C%20%2F%2F%20For%200.2%20stable%20versions%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20format_description%3A%3Awell_known%3A%3ARfc3339%2C%20%2F%2F%20For%200.3.0-alpha-0%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OffsetDateTime%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Ause%20std%3A%3Atime%3A%3ASystemTime%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20to_rfc3339%3CT%3E(dt%3A%20T)%20-%3E%20String%20where%20T%3A%20Into%3COffsetDateTime%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dt.into().format(Rfc3339)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20dt.into().format(%26Rfc3339)%20%2F%2F%20For%200.3.0-alpha-0%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20let%20now%20%3D%20SystemTime%3A%3Anow()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20to_rfc3339(now))%3B%0D%0A%7D)

You will have to add the `formatting` feature to your `Cargo.toml` to use `format_into()` (i.e. formatting on v0.3+ require the feature to be enabled).

Note that you can also specify your own [`strftime`-*like* format](https://docs.rs/time/0.2.26/time/#formatting) string to `format`/`format_into`.