# Is `SystemTime::now` affected by Daylight saving time?

Tags: datetime, rust, time, dst

At time T, I invoke a `SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)`;

At at time T +10, when Daylight saving time has started, I invoke the same call.

Can I expect any weird behavior between the two instances?

Comment: Use the `chrono` package if you want something that can reliably give you a UTC time (which won't be impacted by timezone offsets) or a local time (that will).

Comment: (Or, with the `time` package, use `OffsetDateTime::now_utc` to get a time that won't be impacted by timezone behaviors)

Comment: ...reading the docs for the specific backends used by `SystemTime::now()` on common operating systems, it _looks_ like they generally back into either UTC or epoch time, neither of which is impacted by timezones; so you're probably safe in practice -- but it's better to use something where the docs protect you with solid guarantees in theory _as well as_ practice.

Comment: What do you mean by "back into UTC or epoch time"? 

Isn't the concept of SystemTime supposed to be agnostic of timezones?

Comment: I mean are implemented ("in the backend") by calling OS interfaces that return either UTC (which is timezone-agnostic) or epoch time (which is also timezone-agnostic). So the implementation is documented to be timezone-agnostic _in practice_, but if there are docs also saying it should be timezone-agnostic _in theory_, I've failed at finding them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SystemTime` itself is completely independent of timezones. Timezones, as a concept, talk about how time is displayed to humans in a way that is helpful — `SystemTime` doesn’t talk to humans at all, it just gets the current time. Therefore, as `UNIX_EPOCH` is a point in time completely unaffected by timezones (it is defined to be 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC which is a fixed point in time irrespective of timezone), it is impossible to observe the effects of timezone factors like daylight savings on `SystemTime`.

`chrono` should be used when you wish to show times to users in a human-readable format, or when you wish to parse times from user input, or otherwise do more complex programming that deals with human interpretations of time rather than the raw concept of time and duration itself. Just computing Unix timestamp, for example, should not be done with `chrono` (and `chrono` would not help).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! How do I understand what `SystemTime::now()` actually means?

What is the semantics of time here? As I understand, it's not UTC/GMT/whatever -- it's independent of those things. 



i'm asking because, if two machines output different values to SystemTime::now()` when executed at the same time, then they're clearly not going to give the same unix timestamp. 

In general we should expect machines to give the same unix timestamp though. 

So how is `SystemTime::now()` computed?

Comment: `SystemTime::now()` returns the number of seconds since the Unix epoch — this concept of “absolute time” is just time relative to a known point.

If two machines output different values to `SystemTime::now()` at the same time, they have out-of-sync clocks, by definition. When clocks are in sync they are in sync in every timezone, and have the same Unix timestamp always.

Comment: (nit) 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC which is not really a fixed point in time, it  just pretends to be.  Every time there is a leap second, the epoch lurches back in time by 1 second.  UTC ignores this fact, which leads to many issues/discontinuities. See "Another way to describe this is to say there are as many NTP or POSIX timescales as historic leap seconds..." at https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/leap.html.  The FACTS that the earth does not rotate at a fixed rate, and accurate navigation requires time continuity cannot be ignored or "smeared" (a' la Google's leap sec smearing) away.

Comment: what do you mean the epoch lurches back in time? Sabrina's answer contradicts your statement (iiuc).

Comment: @nz_21 Unix time ignores leap seconds, which means there are moments in UTC time that cannot be represented in Unix time. Since Unix time excludes leap seconds, UTC seconds since the Unix epoch are not the same as Unix time; that's where Unix time "lurches back in time".

Answer (score -1):

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html):

> A measurement of the system clock, useful for talking to external entities like the file system or other processes.
>
> Distinct from the `Instant` type, this time measurement is not monotonic. This means that you can save a file to the file system, then save another file to the file system, and the second file has a `SystemTime` measurement earlier than the first. In other words, an operation that happens after another operation in real time may have an earlier `SystemTime`!

In fact, this could probably happen due to several reasons not just daylight saving time, for example with simple clock synchronization. If these characteristics are not suitable for your use-case, I recommend using [`chrono`](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) as others have suggested in the comments.

Comment: But `chrono` wouldn't be affected by clock synchronization?

Comment: Good question. I do not know. What is the use-case that requires such considerations? Usually the clock is not adjusted by all that much - I have never seen a problem with this. And carefully using timezoned time data should resolve the daylight saving time issue as well.